# checkbox binding [value] not working

Tags: angular

In my form I am trying to bind [value] in a checkbox, however it does not seem to be working.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="deadline"><small>Publishing deadline</small></label><br>
    <input type="text"
        *ngIf="piForm.value.deadline !== 0"
        placeholder="Select date"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="deadline"
        bsDatepicker>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline mt-3">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input"
                name="accountBusinessTypeId"
                type="checkbox"
                formControlName="deadline"
                [value]="0"
                [checked]="piForm.value.deadline === 0">
                No Deadline Required
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the example above, ticking the checkbox should set the value of `deadline` to 0, which would then make the first input disappear as it is set to `*ngIf="piForm.value.deadline !== 0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding (click) event and it will work:

```
<input class="form-check-input"
                name="accountBusinessTypeId"
                type="checkbox"
                formControlName="deadline"
                [value]="0" 
                (click) = "piForm.value.deadline = piForm.value.deadline===0?1:0"
                [checked]="piForm.value.deadline === 0">
```